# Set channel for a device - Parse

Tags: android, parsing, push, channel

How do I set a channel for my device? Like I have a free version of my app and I want to set the channel for all devices running the free version to "free". I tried to use ParsePush.setChannel(); but this is only for sending push's to a certain channel I guess.